# how to specify that I want a generic type to support 'new'

Tags: rust

I want to have a factory method callable from C

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn make<T>() -> *mut T{
        Box::into_raw(Box::new(T::new()))
}
```

this doesn't work because rust doesn't know if T::new exists. I know I would make a trait if I wanted to know that a type supported a foo function that I defined , but new already exists.

Comment: What do you mean by "new already exists"? You have to manually implement `new` for any struct; you don't get it automatically.

Comment: i mean that a function 'new' is something that most types already implement. I know its only by convention, but still its so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike C++, Rust does not have features like template-level implicit interface so it has to be done explicitly, like

```
fn main() {
    make(|| Test::new);
}

pub fn make<T>(cl: impl Fn() -> T) -> *mut T
where {
        Box::into_raw(Box::new(cl()))
}

struct Test;

impl Test{
    fn new() -> Test {
        Test
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0d1fd98e4b97b7116774405aaac9fb6b)

---

Besides that, the `no_mangle` attribute is not useful with generic functions. See the related github [issue](http://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/15844) for more details.

Comment: not callable form C though. I will just have to make my own 'newish' trait and 'impl for' it on those classes I want to make. C# has 'where t:new()' to specifically ask if it has a constructor

Comment: @pm100 `no_mangle` isn't useful with generic functions anyway. See https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/15844

Comment: thats the actual answer - please update so I can tick it

Answer (score 2):

`new` is not a so-called “trait” in *Rust* because the convention by design is open-ended; some `new` constructors take arguments, others don't, some might fail, others are infallible. `new` is purely a conventional name; it otherwise has no significant value in *Rust*. They are called `constructors` by convention, but it is a normal static method.

The trait you seem to be looking for is `Default`, which is defined for types whereof it makes sense to create a new value with no further arguments, creating a sensible default value, such as the number `0`, or the boolean `false`, or an empty collection.

Alternatively, if you seek to convert from a single argument, the trait `From` is what you desire:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn make<T: Default>() -> *mut T{
    Box::into_raw(Box::new(T::default()))
}
```

Or:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn make_from<X, T: From<X>>(x: X) -> *mut T{
    Box::into_raw(Box::new(T::from(x)))
}
```

The `Type: Trait` constraint tells the type system that the type must satisfy a given trait.

If you not be familiar with traits in *Rust* yet, they are an essential part of Rust programming to master.

Comment: i am familiar with traits. I could not see how to create one here (I made NullNew<T> as a trait, but you cannot no_mangle those)

Comment: and of course I just discovered that I cannot no_mangle anything generic. I will have to make a concrete function for each type - ty for your input. I am in the rust ramp up stage where every comment and answer tells me something new